# Cannot get VBA Array to write back to worksheet after making some changes within this project

Tags: excel, vba, matching, dynamic-arrays

I have 10 columns from a worksheet ("Player Tracking") that comes out weekly. I am using that tracking sheet to update a master file worksheet("Player Directory"). This code was doing exactly what it was supposed to do but after adding some improvements to the project this part doesnt work. What did I do?

1 What is supposed to happen with the Player Tracking sheet - The Player ID, Name, screen Name, Agent Name, Agent ID, Fee, RB%, Adj RB, Total Hands, and Cash Hands. SrcColumns Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 14).

2 Player Directory is supposed to be compared with the PLayer Tracking to see if there are any updates or additions. The categories are the same but the rows are slightly different. Trgtcolumns Array(2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17)

3 If there are additions to be made rows are supposed to be added to insure capacity. The last 6 columns are numbers that should just accumulate. so for example. Fee is 7th columns on player tracking. If that cell had a value of 10 and the weekly report had a value of 2. Id want the existing 10 to be added with the 2 so it would now read 12.

Also I am not getting any error codes but my code might be preventing that too. when I run the code it looks like things are happening. even when i step through it everything looks fine but when the sub ends the directory page is still blank.

```
    `Sub DirectoryAdds()
    Const tgtName As String = "Player Directory"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 4
    Const tgtFirstRow As Long = 4
    Dim srcColumns As Variant: srcColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14)
    Dim tgtColumns As Variant: tgtColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17)
    Dim PT As Worksheet: Set PT = PokerBros.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Dim PD As Worksheet: Set PD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Source As Variant, Target As Variant
    Dim NewRow As Long
    Dim Curr As Long
    Dim UB As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
        If PT Is PD Then MsgBox "Wrong sheet selected.": GoTo exitProcedure
    Set rng = PT.Columns(srcColumns(0)).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitProcedure
        If rng.row < srcFirstRow Then GoTo exitProcedure
        Source = PT.Range(PT.Cells(srcFirstRow, srcColumns(0)), rng)
    Set rng = PD.Columns(tgtColumns(0)).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitProcedure
        If rng.row < tgtFirstRow Then GoTo exitProcedure
        Target = PD.Range(PD.Cells(tgtFirstRow, tgtColumns(0)), rng)
        NewRow = rng.row + 1
        UB = UBound(srcColumns)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Source)
            On Error Resume Next
            Curr = WorksheetFunction.Match(Source(i, 1), Target, 0)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                GoSub updateExistingRecord
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
                GoSub addNewRecord
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox "Operation finished successfully."    
        GoTo exitProcedure        
updateExistingRecord:
    Set rng = PD.Cells(Curr + tgtFirstRow - 1, tgtColumns(UB))
        rng.Value = rng.Value + PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(UB)).Value
    Return
addNewRecord:
        For k = 0 To UB - 1
            PD.Cells(NewRow, tgtColumns(k)).Value = _
              PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(k)).Value
        Next k
    Set rng = PD.Cells(NewRow, tgtColumns(UB))
        rng.EntireRow.Insert
        rng.Value = rng.Value + PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(UB)).Value
        NewRow = NewRow + 1
    Return
exitProcedure:
Erase srcColumns
Erase tgtColumns    
updateExistingRecord: Set rng = PD.Cells(Curr + tgtFirstRow - 1, tgtColumns(UB)) rng.Value = 
rng.Value + PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(UB)).Value Return addNewRecord: For k = 0 To 
UB - 1 PD.Cells(NewRow, tgtColumns(k)).Value = _ PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1,  srcColumns(k)).Value 

Next k Set rng = PD.Cells(NewRow, tgtColumns(UB)) rng.EntireRow.Insert  

.Value = rng.Value + PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(UB)).Value NewRow = NewRow + 1 Return exitProcedure: Erase srcColumns Erase tgtColumns End Sub`
```

`

Comment: Use of `GoSub` / `GoTo` (except when setting up error handling) and `Return` (I actually had to look that up) in VBA are *really* uncommon, and typically can be managed more easily using If blocks or other regular flow control.  If you're jumping back and forth using GoTo/GoSub then maybe you really need separate methods for the code you're branching to.

Comment: In addition to Tim Williams: Jumps are unwanted and avoidable in any programming language that follows the structured programming paradigm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will take a look at it. I actually had help on this code and I was really thrilled when it was working. I was using two arrays and looping and still coundnt get the end result i wanted but this was working until I added to it and now it isnt updating. Do you have any suggestions for a better way to do it? I have only been working with code for a year so I am trying to be sponge and absorb as much as I can.

Comment: You said "the directory page is still blank". That suggests the directory page has no existing records and the macro should be adding all the records from the Player Tracking sheet. Is that correct ?

Comment: Correct. when it was working before it did have sample or test data in it. Now since the project is almost complete I wiped it out so it is clean without data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the goto/gosub

Compiled but not tested.

EDIT: simplified/updated to remove the variant arrays

```
Sub DirectoryAdds()

    Const tgtName As String = "Player Directory"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 4
    Const tgtFirstRow As Long = 4
    Dim srcColumns As Variant, tgtColumns As Variant
    Dim PT As Worksheet, PD As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngSource As Range, c As Range
    Dim NewRow As Long, Curr, UB As Long, i As Long, k As Long

    srcColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14)
    tgtColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17)
    UB = UBound(srcColumns)

    Set PT = PokerBros.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) 'what is PokerBros?
    Set PD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)

    If PT Is PD Then
        MsgBox "Wrong sheet selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rngSource = PT.Range(PT.Cells(srcFirstRow, srcColumns(0)), _
                             PT.Cells(Rows.Count, srcColumns(0)).End(xlUp))

    For Each c In rngSource.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            'Simpler to search full column, but assumes there will be no match
            '  in the header or the cells above it...
            Curr = Application.Match(c.Value, PD.Columns(tgtColumns(0)), 0) 'no Worksheetfunction=no runtime error if no match
            If Not IsError(Curr) Then
                'increment last column
                With PD.Cells(Curr, tgtColumns(UB))
                    .Value = .Value + PT.Cells(c.Row, srcColumns(UB)).Value
                End With
            Else
                'no match: copy over
                Set rng = PD.Cells(Rows.Count, tgtColumns(0)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                For k = 0 To UB - 1
                    PD.Cells(rng.Row, tgtColumns(k)).Value = PT.Cells(c.Row, srcColumns(k)).Value
                Next k

                'not sure what the insert is for?
                'rng.EntireRow.Insert
                'rng.Value = rng.Value + PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(UB)).Value
            End If 'got a match
        End If     'have a value to search for
    Next c
    MsgBox "Operation finished successfully."

End Sub
```

Comment: Im still having the same issue. its not writing back to the worksheet. Through debugging I noticed that it is exiting the sub after this line. `If rng.Row < tgtFirstRow Then Exit Sub`.rng is equal to 3 and tgtfirstrow is equal to 4.

Comment: Does your data have headers?  If Yes what row are they in?

Comment: Yes. the headers are in row 3.

Comment: I also found something else interesting. Line 260 contains a row of data. the only thing I see that can be causing that is the source rng is at 259 before rng becomes the variable for the target.

Comment: I re-worked my answer to simplify the approach (removed the variant arrays which just added complexity without any real performance improvement).

Comment: This is working now. Thank you Tim. I apologize for the delay plugging it in but I really appreciate it.